# Read the XML with different elements in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I know, that there are a lot of question about parsing C#, but I couldn't find answer.
So, I need to write a DLL for parsing XML, but with some features, as I don't know what elements are in XML file.  I need to parse all nodes of file and their elements. How can I do it? Now, I'm working with simple file

```
<reg>
    <email_login>paykforcycvert@reincarnate.com</email_login>
    <email_password>nDOUn3TybD</email_password>
</reg>
```

and my dll code now is

```
public XmlNodeList GetElementsName(string path)
{
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(path);
    XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("email_login");
    return nodeList;
}
```

It should return "paykforcycvert@reincarnate.com".
My console app:

```
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker();
string path = "file:///D:/temp/test.xml";
XmlNodeList nodeList = worker.GetElementsName(path);
for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
    Console.WriteLine(nodeList[i].InnerText);
Console.ReadLine();
```

But it returns "paykforcycvert@reincarnate.comnDOUn3TybD"

How can I parse differently?

Comment: Also confirm what @azyberezovsky says, this works fine for me.  The result is `paykforcycvert@reincarnate.com` by itself

Comment: That username/password looks pretty real...

Comment: @Henk Holterman, that username/password was generated by small app) But who knows...)

Answer (score 3):

Use [LINQ to XML](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/LINQtoXML5MinuteOverview.ashx):

```
XElement reg = XElement.Load(path);
string login = (string)reg.Element("email_login");
```

*BTW* your code works fine for me. Make sure you are not selecting all elements instead of `email_login` only. I.e. if you are getting child nodes `XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.ChildNodes;` instead of getting elements by tag name, then you will have your results.

Or possibly you have several elements named as `email_login`. E.g. following xml will produce your results with your code:

```
<reg>
  <email_login>paykforcycvert@reincarnate.com</email_login>
  <email_login>nDOUn3TybD</email_login>
</reg>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
public List<String> getElementValues(string path,string elementName)
{
    XElement doc= XElement.Load(path);
    var elementList=doc.Descendants().Elements();
    return elementList.Where(x=>x.Name.LocalName==elementName)
                      .Select(y=>y.Value)
                      .ToList();
}
```

You can now get all the values of element with name `email_login`

```
var values=getElementValues(path,"email_login");
```

Answer (score 0):

i ran the exact same code you gave and got `paykforcycvert@reincarnate.com` as output so my guess is that you haven't build your project after you fixed something or it wasn't cleaned.

try to clean the project and run it again

Answer (score 0):

I ran following code after coping the XML data you provided in XMLFile.xml to emulate output:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker();
        //
        string path = @"C:\Users\abc\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\XMLFile.xml";
        XmlNodeList nodeList = worker.GetElementsName(path);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(nodeList[i].InnerText);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }       
}

public class XMLWorker
{
    public XmlNodeList GetElementsName(string path)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(path);
        XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("email_login");

        return nodeList;
    }
}
```

But for me it is working fine.

Comment: That was already said by me, by NoIdeaForName, and by SwDevMan81 in comments

Comment: Yes...now lets see what we get here causing the issue !!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [XPath](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308333) query:

```
XmlNodesList nodesList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//email_login"));
foreach(string oneNode in nodesList) 
{
    Console.Write(oneNode.InnerText);
}
```